# Basic HTTP Authentication in Flask AttributeError: 'NoneType' error

Tags: python, http, flask, basic-authentication

I'm doing a Flask app and I need to do HTTP Basic Authentication and it doesn't work

I'm doing like in [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VW8qJxy4XcQ)

What do I need to do in order to fix this problem?

Imported libraries

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, render_template_string, request
import json
```

Code fragment with auth

```py
@app.route('/user/<string:name>')
def user(name):
    request.authorization.username
    request.authorization.password

    with open('json/users.json', 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        x = f.read()
    data = json.loads(x)
    user = data[name]
    return render_template('about_user.html',
        _name=user['name'],
        _age=user['age'],
        _discord=user['discord']
    )
```

An error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Comment: What line is the error in?

Comment: @Patch I placed this page on hosting, Flask returning a page with error explanation

Comment: @Patch Line Nr.3 and line Nr.4

Comment: Can you please show me the JSON data in `data`? and just curious why would you use underscore for the value name?

Comment: @Patch Problem in line `request.authorization.username`, but not in json file

Comment: @Patch From linux(server) console: ```File "/home/pi/Desktop/Flask/site/main.py", line 12, in user
    request.authorization.username
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Comment: @Patch I'm doing all auth code from example(link located in question) and in example all works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check if there is a `request.authorization` first so

```
  if request.authorization:
    request.authorization.username
    request.authorization.password

    with open('json/users.json', 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        x = f.read()
    data = json.loads(x)
    user = data[name]
    return render_template('about_user.html',
        _name=user['name'],
        _age=user['age'],
        _discord=user['discord']
    )


    else:
       return make_response(....)
```

make sure you import `make_response`.

Comment: and I needed to add ```make_response()```